# Chart.js Point image on hover

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have set `pointStyle` to an image in a Chart.js line chart, but I'm looking to have the point hidden until it's hovered.

This is where I create the image variable:

```
var point = new Image();
point.src = 'path/to/image.png';
```

This is my options object:

```
{
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['13 Oct 2019', '14 Oct 2019', '15 Oct 2019', '16 Oct 2019'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'paid',
            borderColor: '#ffffff',
            data: [5, 35, 15, 45],
            fill: false,
            pointStyle: point
        }]
    }
}
```

This shows the image as the point, but of course not only on hover. I'd like to hide the point completely until it's hovered, and when hovered only show *that* point.

When not using an image, these are the options I used to show the point only on hover:

```
{
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['13 Oct 2019', '14 Oct 2019', '15 Oct 2019', '16 Oct 2019'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'paid',
            borderColor: '#ffffff',
            data: [5, 35, 15, 45],
            fill: false,
            pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
            pointHoverBorderColor: '#ffffff',
        }]
    }
}
```

I also thought about showing a 1 pixel transparent image as the point until it's hovered, but I'm not sure how I could change the image on hover either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this Chart.js issue?](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1153)

> `Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 0` hides the point but
>
> `Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 4` only shows it on hover.

This should work with your `pointStyle`.